# Android Retrofit Fetch Data Based On User Input

Tags: java, android, mysql, retrofit

This scenario involves passing a string data from one activity to another.  I want to use this variable(useremail) to select the data in a mysql database. The data is not returning anything from server. I am trying to do this using retrofit. Where could i be going wrong?.

API INTERFACE

```
public interface ApiInterface2 {
    String BASE_URL = "10.0.2.2/uploadmultiple/";
    @POST("mylist.php")
    Call<List<ImageList>> getImgData(@Query("useremail") String userEmail);}
```

MAIN CLASS

```
  Call<List<ImageList>> call = apiInterface.getImgData(userEmail);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ImageList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ImageList>> call, Response<List<ImageList>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {

                        imageLists = response.body();
                        adapter = new ListingsAdapter(imageLists, MyListings.this);
           ////////
 });
```

```
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

    $useremail = $_POST["useremail"];

    if(empty($useremail)){echo "UserEmail is null";}

try {

    $email = $_REQUEST["useremail"];
    // Create connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$HostName;dbname=$DatabaseName", $HostUser, $HostPass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tabe1` WHERE `useremail` = $email"); 

    $stmt->execute();

    $data=array();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $row; 
    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Connection failed! Please Try Again Or Contact Us: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    $conn = null;
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: you use method "POST" in php. but in app used GET. Please make method call as  in PHP

Comment: I have tried both Post and get but it is not working

Comment: Try to use ` @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("mylist.php")
Call<List<ImageList>> getImgData(@Field("useremail") String userEmail);`

Comment: How do you return data from api call, can you tell me or show code of that?

Comment: I think if you are using POST method in retrofit, then you instead of using Query, you need to pass the data as a Field

Comment: @PriyankaC Check Edit fr ful PHP Code and return statement.

Comment: do you try as I said in comment?. and get "useremail" in php using $_POST['useremail'] . You have to first check your api is correct or not like in postman. If it is working then you have to check for issue in retrofit.

Comment: ok. Let me trubleshoot my php code!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was finally resolved by handling the API side well. Thanks to all of the respondents.

API INTERFACE

```
public interface ApiInterface2 {
    String BASE_URL = "10.0.2.2/uploadmultiple/";
    @POST("mylist.php")
    Call<List<ImageList>> getImgData(@Query("useremail") String userEmail);}
```

MAIN CLASS

```
  Call<List<ImageList>> call = apiInterface.getImgData(userEmail);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ImageList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ImageList>> call, Response<List<ImageList>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {

                        imageLists = response.body();
                        adapter = new ListingsAdapter(imageLists, MyListings.this);
           ////////
 });
```

```
<?php


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    try{ 

    $useremail = $_REQUEST["useremail"];
    include 'dbconfig.php';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$HostName;dbname=$DatabaseName", $HostUser, $HostPass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `useremail` = '$useremail'"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $data=array();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $row; 
    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Connection failed! Please Try Again Or Contact Us: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";

    die();
    $conn = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this, **BASE_URL** should contain the **URL** only in **retrofit** not the path.

```
String BASE_URL = "10.0.2.2/";
@POST("uploadmultiple /mylist.php")
```

This should help you.

Comment: No, It is not true. BASE_URL can be anything. A path to a script is also a URL and can be passed in the base url

Comment: Could you add your Error Log, please